# How does the Sitecore SharePoint Connector name its items?

Tags: sharepoint, sitecore, sitecore6

Can anyone who has used the Sitecore SharePoint connector tell me how it chooses the name for the items it creates in the Sitecore tree?

I am able to map fields and sitecore values (such as __Displayname), but not the tree name.

The problem we face is that the data in SharePoint contains invalid characters that should not be allowed in the tree name.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, SharePoint connector chooses Sitecore item name by iterating through the following SharePoint fields in that very order:

- Title
- LinkFilename
- LinkTitle
- NameOrTitle
- URL
- GUID
- ID

If the field is not empty, its value is taken as an item name and the iteration stops. So you can find out where the invalid name comes from in your case. If it's NameOrTitle, for instance, then you can try to put a valid name to, let's say, Title and it should be picked by SharePoint connector.

I've never tried this myself, though. That's what I can judge about looking at the code.

Also, the documentation for SharePoint connector for Sitecore 6 is [here](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/sitecore6modules/sharepoint/sharepoint_connector_module_installation_and_configuration_guide.pdf).